# Action Bar, by default the buttons are snapped to the right, how do I space them out

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I got rid of the icon and label on my action bar and got 3 buttons to navigate to certain parts of the app. The problem is the buttons are all squashed to one side of the action bar! How do I have it spaced out? I would love to have one on the left of the action bar, one in the middle and one on the right. Making it look more neat and tidy for my users :)

Comment: Can you post any image of your actionbar output??

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things ,

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {        
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

// ...

// Find the icon(Button); make it aligned to right or left or center, also in expanded mode:

<"your bttn">.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
<"your bttn2">.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.LEFT));
<"your bttn3">.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.CENTER));
```

}

Comment: What gets inserted in <"your bttn"> ? the id of the button ?